# python get http request really slow, more than 20s

Tags: python

I am trying to hit the NPI(National Provider Identification) API to search a doctor. I do it in Python. I have tried using two libraries. requests and urllib2. super slow(more than 20 second to get back response).

```
url = 'https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/'
params = {
    'first_name': first_name,
    'last_name': last_name,
    'limit': 200,
}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(url, params).json()
```

their demo is super fast. when I use Postman and cURL is super fast too.

so I am guessing this is a problem with Python, any idea about it?
any workaround?

p.s i am using python 2.7 and Django 1.10. any Django solution is welcome too

p.s API return valid response. it's just suuper slow

You can try this code too. the API is free and public and requests no authentication

Comment: Just timed it at `0.272056818008`.

Comment: Maybe the server is rate-limiting your Python agent in order to prevent spam and bots

Comment: is pyOpenSSL installed?

Comment: As we know that there is no reason that some lungauges has delay in response or not. API is same for all programming languagaes.

Comment: And is the response ok?, does it return the wanted data?

Comment: @RafaelBarros it happens for the most of time, and how do you get this number?

Comment: @cricket_007 do these two libraries send out some special headers?

Comment: What are you using for first/last name?

Comment: @zwer python string

Comment: @doratheexplorer0911 yep. just super slow

Comment: @Mandraenke not really. how does this help?

Comment: Is python slow or Django?
Have you tried it from python console?
Is it the same slow?

Comment: If you want to enable others to test it too, consider actually making your example a [mcve]. To be complete and verifiable, in particular, it can't refer to undefined variables; provide samples of valid values.

Comment: and btw, CNR here (less than two seconds running your code, with `(first_name, last_name) = ('Test', 'Test')`).

Comment: You are connecting to HTTPS site, which is why pyOpenSSL would change something

Comment: Anyhow, if you want to be sure the issue is an issue with the client HTTP stack (as opposed to server-side rate-limiting, a transient network error, different DNS configuration between your test clients or who-knows-what-else), you'll want to use a packet sniffer such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to actually look at the network traffic. Until that's been established, all is speculation, and the question is effectively unanswerable. ('Twould be less so if the issue reproduced for people other than you, but it appears that it *doesn't*).

Comment: If we are sharing results - I can't even access the site, it keeps timing out even from a browser.

Comment: pyOpenSSL might be faster than SSL done in pure Python. Just give it a try.

Comment: @iiylll python. tried on terminal. no luck

Comment: Did you get your issue with this resolved? I'm actually experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Dan yeah turns out it's just network issue